# How can a python class have a variable attribute that gives a varaible result when called?

Tags: python-3.x, class

Here is the context:
an RPG where I have defined a "Dice" class so that random numbers can be easily obtained.  I want to have a magic spell cause damage as the result of a dice roll.

```
import random
class Dice:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def get_dice(self):
        return random.randrange(1, int(self.value + 1))

d4 = Dice("d4", 4)
d6 = Dice("d6", 6)
d8 = Dice("d8", 8)

dice = [d4, d6, d8]

class Spell:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def get_spell_damage(self):
        return self.value

fire = Spell("fire", d8.get_dice())
ice  = Spell("ice", d6.get_dice() + d6.get_dice())
wind = Spell("wind", d4.get_dice() + d4.get_dice() + d4.get_dice())

spellbook = [fire, ice, wind]
```

The problem is that the dice are rolled the when the spell is defined, and not each time it is called.  If I say:

```
print(str(ice.get_spell_damage()), str(ice.get_spell_damage()), str(ice.get_spell_damage()))
```

When I get a results like "7 7 7", it tells me that within spellbook[ice].value, each "d6.get_dice()" is giving unique results, but it now has a defined value.

How should the code be changed so that each time the spell is called it is evaluated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `__init__` method of `Spell` take a list of `Dice`s instead, and make the `get_spell_damage` call the `get_dice` method of each dice in the list and sum the rolls:

```
class Spell:
    def __init__(self, name, dices):
        self.name = name
        self.dices = dices

    def get_spell_damage(self):
        return sum(dice.get_dice() for dice in self.dices)

fire = Spell("fire", [d8])
ice  = Spell("ice", [d6, d6])
wind = Spell("wind", [d4, d4, d4])
```

And if you need to a `Spell` that has a static damage value, you can create a subclass of `Dice` whose `get_dice` method always returns a fixed value:

```
class StaticDice(Dice):
    def get_dice(self):
        return self.value
```

so that you can create a spell that has a static damage value like this:

```
earth = Spell("earth", [StaticDice('s10', 10)])
```

Comment: Thank you, this works quite nicely.  The only problem this introduced is that I want to have options where a spell has a static damage value.  I got around this by adding self.value_type to the spell class, and then the get_spell_damage has a in/then statement to call self.value_type == "static" or variable.